# assign new value to private field of mocked class

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

Assigning a new instance of HashSet to private field of mocked class is the main problem. In the mocked class, I try to assign new value to private field. As a result, I have done below implementation; however, it seems reflection is not works on the mocked class. Thus, how can I assign new value to private field of mocked class with Powermockito?

my implementation

```
 class Foo{
    private volatile Set<String> field;
 }
```

With reflection

```
  Foo mock = mock(Foo.class);

  try{
       Field refField = mock.getClass().getDeclaredField("field");
       ...
  }catch( ... ) {

  }
```

getDeclaredField throws exception of "NoSuchFieldException".

What I aim to achieve is, in case of exception is not thrown;

```
   refField.set(mock, new HashSet<String>());
```

Comment: A mock has all its methods replaced (or rather, overridden) by other methods that do nothing. So changing the field of a mock won't serve any purpose, since all its methods don't use this field at all. Your class under test uses *methods* of the mock. So use the mock API to tell the mock what these *methods* should do. The private fields are irrelevant. What matters is the public API of the mocked object, used by the class under test.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve it. Interesting but works.

```
Foo fooInstance = new Foo();

try {
   whenNew(Foo.class).withAnyArguments().then(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Field reflected = invocation.getClass().getDeclaredField("field");
            reflected.setAccessible(true);
            reflected.set(fooInstance, (new HashSet<String>()));

            return null;
        }

});
} catch (Exception e) {
      ....
}
```

After asking this question, [one link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120820/mockito-mocked-object-is-assigned-a-null-value-from-method-calls-inside-a-method) from right-hand side, as suggestion, has got my interest. I have found answer after look at that question, sort of inspiration.